# Is there a web admin panel for django-celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm using django-celery for the first time today. 
I already got it working in my production server with RabbitMQ, a daemonized worker, all pretty.

Now, it would be nice to be able to see tasks/queues state in some kind of web-based admin panel that shows what tasks are in the queues right now and how many have been executed in the last 60 seconds, and things like that.

Does django-celery has such a feature? Or maybe is there any known django app that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Flower](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor) from Celery. A real-time web based monitor and administration tool for Celery.